# Docker Wordpress timeout limit error db connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, digital-ocean

For the first time I'm using Docker on Digital Ocean for a Wordpress installation. The setup is ok, also the theme installation, but when I install the Revolution Slider plugin the server show me: "Error establishing a database connection".

Plugin installed successfully.

**Warning**: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877

**Warning**: mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877

IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             **STATUS**
mysql:latest            "docker-entrypoint..."   About an hour ago   **Restarting (1) 12 minutes ago**

I restarted all the container, Wordpress works but I can't see any Plugin and the Theme page show me only "ERROR: The theme directory themename does not exist", but looking the FTP the directory is there. Any suggestion? Thanks!

docker-compose.yml

```html
version: '2'
services:
  digitalpmi:
    container_name: digitalpmi_wp
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=[ip]
    - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=dpdb
    - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=dp_
    - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=[password]
    networks:
      - front
      - back
  db:
    container_name: digitalpmi_db
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:[password]
    networks:
      - back
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:[password]
    networks:
      - back
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - front
networks:
  front:
  back:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mysql-crashes-often-mysql-gone-away-in-wp-dbphp-file/

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe Ok, but on my SFTP I can only see these folder: languages  plugins  themes  upgrade  uploads. There isn't a wp-db.php file.